# how use server-celery with flask

Tags: python, flask, celery

I installed celery-server 3.0.0 to flask and then I started the  server, but when I used the server to run a python code backgroud I find this error.

> ~/Bureau$ sudo python exme.py
>   Traceback (most recent call
>   last):
>    File "exme.py", line 2, in 
>       from celery import Celery
>  ImportError: No module named celery

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.update(
CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
@celery.task() 
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
@APP.route('/test',methods=['POST'])
def test():
 try:
   result=add_together.delay(5,2) 
   return result
 except Exception as e: 

    return e
```

Comment: You use in a place `app` and then `APP`. Replace `APP` with `app` in all places.

Comment: thanks @doru but I have the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have proprely installed `celery` by running `pip install --upgrade celery` in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need to use `sudo` to run your app. When you use `sudo`, your environment variables are not carried over and you loose your virtualenv. Run your app like this instead:

```
$ python exme.py
```